# inter-Solr-node communication with SSL

Tags: ssl, solr, solrcloud

Again, I have some problems with Solr. I'm trying to set up a SolrCloud cluster with three ZooKeeper instances and two Solr instances. Communication should be secured with SSL. I used the official Solr wiki as manual: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL

When I start the first Solr node everything works fine. I can access the Web UI via HTTP**S** and communication between Solr and ZooKeeper also works. But when I start the second Solr node in my cluster I get the following exception:

```
Error while trying to recover. core=core1_shard2_replica2:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8983/solr
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.sendPrepRecoveryCmd(RecoveryStrategy.java:593)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:350)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$22(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:604)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.lambda$httpUriRequest$13(HttpSolrClient.java:299)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:495)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:352)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:219)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:347)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
```

So it seems that Solr does not accept the self-signed certificate. The option `-Dsolr.ssl.checkPeerName=false` as stated in the Solr Wiki has no effect (I put this parameter in the `solr.in.sh` script). I have to admit I'm pretty clueless right now :(

Does anyone have any idea what I could do to make the inter-Solr-node communication work?

BTW: I'm on Solr 6.1.0, and before I activated SSL everything worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Finally, the inter-node communication is working. We use Let's Enrypt for the certificates and we must import the certificates from all other nodes in each node. The `Dsolr.ssl.checkPeerName=false` is - as of today - ignored: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9304

Answer (score 1):

You can also add second node's certificate to the first node's keystore and also add first node's certificate to the second node's keystore via following command:

`keytool -import -alias ca -file other_node_cert -keystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks`

Then you can use self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at exception details it appears to be a handshake issue between java client code and the ssl enabled server. The JRE involved here probably doesn't trust the certificate. You can try to mark the cert as a trusted one (include in JRE truststore). Check JRE version specific documentation for steps to update truststore.