# Should each SolrCloud node have its own ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, solr, sitecore, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm attempting to enable SSL for SolrCloud to be used with Sitecore. I currently have an external assembly of three Zookeeper nodes on three Azure vms and two Solr 6.6.6 nodes on two Azure vms.

I'm following the steps outlined in Apache's documentation: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/enabling-ssl.html

Should I generate a separate certificate for each of the nodes or should I only create it on one and share it in some way? I was thinking that maybe in the later steps that Zookeeper distributes it someway but the directions are unclear to me.

I did check for similar questions and found this: [inter-Solr-node communication with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228425/inter-solr-node-communication-with-ssl) but it doesn't really address whether I should be generating separate certificates to begin with or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account setup what you described, you can even make it more simple by off-loading SSL on Application Gateway (I can assume you are using Azure App Gateway to balance traffic to Solr nodes) and then forwarding request from App Gateway to Solr Nodes over HTTP (no SSL)
If you configure your ZK and Solr nodes to communicate by internal IP address and vnet/nsg to let only requests from App Gateway, this setup won’t have any security impact.

If you insist keeping SolrCloud using SSL, I believe that should be one single certificate.
Note: don’t forget to let Zookeeper to know that whole SolrCloud should use SSL by setting a parameter (see step #7 as an example here https://github.com/ivanbuzyka/Sitecore.SolrCloudConfiguration/wiki/3.-Install-Zookeeper-as-a-service)

Comment: I changed from separate certificates to a single certificate and was finally able to create a collection (prior to this I couldn't create a collection and got signature doesn't match in the logs.
Thanks for the additional information about using gatekeeper. I may try that for production.